# How do you make 5 images: 2 columns, 2 columns, 1 column, centered and responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, image-size

I'm trying to create a page with 5 images that maintain the structure until under 360px where it goes into single column evenly spaced.

Wondering what the best solution would be to this?

I've tried messing around with the responsivegridsystem.com method but I'm a little confused by it, and the issue of the 5th image staying centered and the same size is required.

Looking to be able to adjust the sizing of the pictures and the spacing between and around them if that's possible?

Thank you

desktop:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sEKC.jpg

mobile:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKmXg.jpg

Comment: please include your current code, both CSS and HTML markup, if you're using some kind of framework like Bootstrap, Foundation, Gridpak, etc, and/or any other relevant detail to the question. As it is now, it has countless answers and looks as if you're looking for some free coding service

Comment: Are you using a responsive framework? i.e. bootstrap?

Comment: @Fabio There's not enough room for the code, I've downloaded the code from http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/downloads/responsivegridsystem.zip and placed my pictres in the 2 column div.

Comment: @Rook I'm using http://www.responsivegridsystem.com framework, I downloaded the zip file and put my images into the code.